Is there a way to set a "clamp to border" style texture wrap mode in Unity?
When editing a texture in the inspector, there is an option for "Wrap Mode", but there is no option for clamp-to-border (equivalent of e.g. GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER in OpenGL). And the docs seem to suggest this isn't available via scripting either.

This is, needless to say, a big problem when dealing with UI sprites. It's possible to work around this issue in most cases by manually adding large transparent gutters around every texture and editing the sprite bounds accordingly, but that's obviously suboptimal and a pain in the ass.
Is there really no way to use a clamp-to-border sampling mode on textures in Unity? What am I missing here?
